# Fill fields in webview programmatically

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I was trying to insert values into fields in a webpage loaded inside a webview .

***The exact thing i was doing was this -***

```
String date = "5/8/1994";
webview.loadUrl("javascript:var uselessvar_a =document.getElementById('dpStudentdob_dateInput').value='" + date + "';");
```

***Problem***

- So this is suppose to insert the value into the field into the given
  id. and it gives me the exact result , it insert into the field. but
  when the submit button is pressed the error is shown as this data is
  not correct. but when i insert the values by typing the same value is
  accepted.
- The problem is with inserting value into the DOB field in the
  webpage.
- The registration number field works fine and the clicking button also
  works fine in my code.

the webpage is was loading is [this](http://www.bputexam.in/StudentSection/ResultPublished/StudentResult.aspx).

I want to enter the date into the date DOB field in the webpage.

***My full java class is-***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            String password = "1201329022";
            String date = "5/8/1994";
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:var uselessvar =document.getElementById('txtRegNo').value='" + password + "';");
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:var uselessvar_a =document.getElementById('dpStudentdob_dateInput').value='" + date + "';");
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:var uselessvar_b =document.getElementById('btnView').click();");
        }
    });

    webview.loadUrl("http://bputexam.in/StudentSection/ResultPublished/StudentResult.aspx");
}

}
```

*Do any one have any suggestion for this.*

Comment: You did not tell the difference between those two fields. And you forgot to post the source of the form.

Comment: Add a little bit javascript to read the value from that field and compare typed in case with the code case.

Comment: Do not start AsyncTasks in threads. Why an AsyncTask if you only use OnPostExecte? Makes no sense.

Comment: `class clickbutton extends AsyncTask`. So you are calling your AsyncTask clickbutton. You like to write unreadable code?

Comment: hey @greenapps i have edited my code . i was just trying every way possible to make my code work. but i failed.

Answer (score 0):

To insert text inside an input text field in webview you have to use javascript like below:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){l=document.getElementById('form1:txtDrname').value='" + editTextInput.getText().toString() + "';})()");
```

Then you can click a button inside webview to perform search:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){l=document.getElementById('form1:btnSubmit');e=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');e.initEvent('click',true,true);l.dispatchEvent(e);})()");
```